# Regex where all strings containing an even number of 0's:

Tags: automata, finite-automata, regular-expressions

Question is to construct a regex where all strings containing an even number of 0's:
By constructing DFA graphically, it is

$$(1^*+01^*0)^* $$

But it is also

$$1^*(01^*01^*)^*$$

Can we prove that they are equal algebraically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the wikipedia page on [Kleene Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_algebra), we can use two properties:

- $(a^*)^*= a^*$
- $(a+b)^* = a^*(b(a^*))^*$

If you allow those it is quite straightforward:

$(1^∗+01^∗0)^∗ = (1^∗)^*\cdot (01^∗0(1^*)^* )^∗ = 1^∗(01^∗01^* )^∗$.

There is probably not a single set of rules for equivalence of regular expressions that everyone egrees on. The rules at wikipedia that I used above are from Dexter Kozen (A completeness Theorem for Kleene Algebras[...], [Information and Computation, 1994](https://doi.org/10.1006/inco.1994.1037), open access). The second rule we applied is Proposition 2.7 in that Kozen article. In his notation Kozen uses a partial order $x\leq y$ to represent $x+y= y$. Earlier approaches came from Arto Salomaa (1966) and John Conway (1971). See the History section at wikipedia. I did not study the approaches so I have no comment on this.

Here a (I think) complete set of rules, copied from a [presentation](https://perso.telecom-paristech.fr/jsaka/CONF/Files/AE-180228.pdf#page=56) of Jacques Sakarovitch. Here that specific rule is called "denesting". It seems an essential rule.

$$
\begin{array}{rc}
\text{trivial} &
E+0 = 0 + E = E   \\
 & E\cdot 0 = 0 \cdot E = 0\\
 & E\cdot 1 = 1 \cdot E = E
\\
\text{associative} &
(E_1+E_2)+E_3 = E_1+(E_2+E_3)\\
 & (E_1\cdot E_2)\cdot E_3 = E_1\cdot (E_2\cdot E_3)
\\
\text{distributive} &
E (E_1+E_2) = EE_1+EE_2\\
 &  (E_1+E_2)E = E_1E+E_2E
\\
\text{commutative} &
E_1+E_2 = E_2+E_1
\\[0.5ex]
\text{unrolling}  &
E^* = 1 + EE^* = 1 + E^*E  
\\
\text{denesting} &
(E_1+E_2)^* = E_1^* \cdot (E_2\cdot E_1^*)^*
\\
\text{sliding} &
(E_1\cdot E_2)^*\cdot E_1 = E_1\cdot (E_2\cdot E_1)^* 
\\[0.5ex]
\text{cyclic Zn} &
E^* = (1 + E + E^2 + \dots E^{n-1})\cdot (E^n)^*
\\[0.5ex]
\text{idempotency} &
E+E=E\\
 & (E^*)^* = E^* 
\end{array}$$

Comment: I haven't seen Kleene Algebra, is the 2nd equivalence came out sementically or from set of rules?

Comment: @steatoda Good question. I added some comments.